# HTTPS without installing a trusted CA certificate on browsers

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ca, tls1.2

I have some local virtual servers simulating an Intranet at home. I have server who acts as a Root CA and also as a Intermediate CA. I have a web server configured to use HTTPS with a certificate signed by the intermediate CA.

Question: Is there a way to use HTTPS without installing the Root Certificate or the certificate chain file on every web browser of the Intranet clients?

Answer (score 0):

No, the certificates must be installed into the CA root trust store on each individual system. If you have a domain with Windows clients you can use group policy objects to perform the distribution but other than that I'm afraid you'll need to do it the old fashioned way (which can be cumbersome depending upon the platform; like chromebooks).

Comment: To add to this point. you have to have a certificate,  but it can be one you make and trust yourself.